# how to write javascript or jquery validation for below code in mvc4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to validate a `TextBox` as a required field if user checks any of the check boxes.

How do I validate the above requirement .Can anybody help?

Below is the View code snippet.

```
<div>
         <div id="">
            <input type="checkbox"  id="partsChk" name="partsChk"/><label      
            class="enrollment_side">
                Parts (including IRFs)
            </label>
        </div>


          <div id="">
            @Html.TextBox("PartsTitle","", new { @class = "enrollment_tbox", placeholder 
              = "Parts Contact Title (i.e. Parts Manager)" })


             <br />
            @Html.TextBox("PartsFirstName", "", new { placeholder = "First Name" })
            @Html.TextBox("PartsLastName","", new { placeholder = "Last Name" })
            @Html.TextBox("PartsEmpId","",  new { placeholder = "BMW Employee ID" })


            <br />

            </div>

             </div>


            <div>
         <div id="">
           <input type="checkbox" id="salesChk" name="salesChk" /><label  
        class="enrollment_sidehdr">Sales – Coming in Q3 2014
            </label>
        </div>


             <div id=""> 
        @Html.TextBox("SalesTitle","", new { @class = "enrollment_tbox", placeholder =  
        "Sales Contact Title (i.e. Sales Manager)" })

            <br />

          @Html.TextBox("SalesFirstName", "", new { placeholder = "First Name" })
            @Html.TextBox("SalesLastName","", new { placeholder = "Last Name" })
            @Html.TextBox("SalesEmpId","",  new { placeholder = "BMW Employee ID" })

        </div>

       </div>


     <div>
      <div id="">
       <input type="checkbox" id="serviceChk" name="serviceChk" /><label  
       class="enrollment_sidehdr">Service – Coming in Q3 2014
            </label>
        </div>


        <div id="">
           @Html.TextBox("ServiceTitle","", new { @class = "enrollment_tbox", 
        placeholder = "Service Contact Title (i.e. Service Manager)" })
            <br />

           @Html.TextBox("ServiceFirstName", "", new { placeholder = "First Name" })
            @Html.TextBox("ServiceLastName","", new { placeholder = "Last Name" })
            @Html.TextBox("ServiceEmpId","",  new { placeholder = "BMW Employee ID" })


            <br />

        </div>

         </div>
```

Comment: So you have multiple checkboxes related to each text field ?

Comment: Yes i have mutiple textboxes related to groups of textboxes.ie., for each group i have one checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer this sample code. I've written the HTML and jQuery code, Integrate it in your application

**HTML**

```
Group 1
<input type="checkbox"  id="1" class="cb"/>
<input type="text" class="txt1">
<input type="text" class="txt1">
    <br/>
    <br/>
Group 2
<input type="checkbox"  id="2" class="cb"/>
<input type="text" class="txt2">
<input type="text" class="txt2">
    <br/>
    <br/>
Group 3
<input type="checkbox"  id="3" class="cb"/>
<input type="text" class="txt3">
<input type="text" class="txt3">
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="button" id="button1" value="click me" />
```

**jQuery**

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
    $(".cb").each(function(){
        var flag = 0;
        if($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            $(".txt" + $(this).attr("id")).each(function(){
                if($(this).val() == "")
                {
                    flag = 1;
                }
            });
            if(flag == 1)
            {
                alert("Fields of Group " + $(this).attr("id") + " are empty, Please fill it");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**[Live demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/SH3DJ/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

If your naming convention is same as you wrote You can use following code ...

Change ids of your checkboxes to PartsChk, SalesChk and ServiceChk respectively. and then write following script

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
       if($(this).is(':checked')){
             var prefix=$(this).id.replace('Chk','');
             if($('#'+prefix+'Title').val()==''){
                    alert(prefix+'Title Field can not be left Empty');
                    $('#'+prefix+'Title').focus();
              }
              else if($('#'+prefix+'FirstName').val()==''){
                    alert(prefix+'FirstName Field can not be left Empty');
                    $('#'+prefix+'FirstName').focus();
              }
              else if($('#'+prefix+'LastName').val()==''){
                    alert(prefix+'LastName Field can not be left Empty');
                    $('#'+prefix+'LastName').focus();
              }
              else if($('#'+prefix+'EmpId').val()==''){
                    alert(prefix+'EmpId Field can not be left Empty');
                    $('#'+prefix+'EmpId').focus();
              }
       }
}
```

This JQuery code will give exactly what you want, It'll give alert if field is left blank if corressponding checkbox is checked and after that focus to the blank element..